# Send user config to slack of an individual user

Tags: bash, slack, slack-api, slack-commands

Related to my assigned project, I wrote a bash script to implement the task.

For the user account and secret/hash creation part, the manager told me to find a way to send the user config file content directly to the individual user's slack(not a channel with a group of people in it). How to do that?.

I can see, search gives me the result of sending to slack channel using curl with short text messages.

I am not sure how to do the following:

- Send a config file content to an individual user's slack.

Suppose, if the user account, password, hashes generated in the file /root/user_config. I want to send the file content to the individual user's slack(not channel or group).

Answer (score 0):

From purely Slack Conversations perspective,

You need to DM the user using following APIs :

1. Open Conversation (Get DM Id):

    https://api.slack.com/methods/conversations.open
2. Post Message using DM Id :

    https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.postMessage

What data you need to send is up to you.

Comment: Thank you Suyashm but seems this is also related to the slack channel right?

Comment: It is, but I believe you need it for DM, and it lets you do that.